# Robotframework - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I am trying to make a simple POST to the API but keep getting  Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'.
I have tried using a different API to make a POST request and it works without any problems. The difference was that it didn't require header information.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     RequestsLibrary
Library     Collections
Library     OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${baseUrl}      https://simple-books-api.glitch.me
${headers}      Content-Type=application/json;charset=utf-8   Authorization=Bearer 9daaef9d38b7bff40af6400bba8fffb7a466e778ecd3068d9a9766d231491bc2


*** Test Cases ***
OrderBook
create session  mysession   ${baseUrl}  verify=true
${body}=    create dictionary       bookId=1  customerName=John Doe
LOG TO CONSOLE     ${body}
${response}=    post on session    mysession   /orders     data=${body}    headers=${headers}
log to console  ${response}

log to console    ${response.status_code}
log to console    ${response.content}

#validations
${res_body}=    convert to string   ${response.content}
should contain    ${res_body}   true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue came from the way you defined the `${headers}` variable - in the Variables section you need to prefix with `&` to get a dictionary. Just change it to this and it should be fine:

```
*** Variables ***
${baseUrl}      https://simple-books-api.glitch.me
&{headers}      Content-Type=application/json;charset=utf-8   Authorization=Bearer 9daaef9d38b7bff40af6400bba8fffb7a466e778ecd3068d9a9766d231491bc2
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, it worked!
I also had to change data=${body} to json=${body}